# How do I turn off in console gradle build message like 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'?

Tags: gradle

I want to export project version to environment

by `tag=`'gradle printVersion'`

`printVersion` is gradle task

```
task exportVersion {
    println project.version
}
```

it print `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` to console, and my $tag env is set to `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:exportVersionUP-TO-DATEBUILD SUCCESSFUL`

How do I make the gradle to include :exportVersion, BUILD SUCCESSFUL to console?

Comment: I'm not sure this will be something that's possible, and it feels like an odd solution to a common problem. Do I understand correctly that you're just trying to get the version number for use in some other process? Could you write it to a file instead? Or, given that you're calling the variable `tag`, if you're just planning on using it to create a tag in your version control system, why not make your gradle task do that? The [gradle release plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) might even be useful in what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes this is weird, I could create an maven upload task, but I don't have company nexus username/password. This will run on Jenkins server as a mvn deploy file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have your task misconfigured. This way version will be printed every time gradle is run. To avoid it you should add an action: `<<` or `doLast`. To suppress gradle output, use `-q` switch:

```
>cat build.gradle 
task exportVersion << {
    println project.version
}

>gradle -q exportVersion
unspecified
```

P.S. @DaveyDaveDave is right, it shouldn't be handled that way.

Comment: this is exactly I want, now my tag is `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` with -q option.

Comment: Adding `--console plain` seems to help, too.