# how to programmatically turn off gradle build message 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project that is just used for running JavaExec tasks.  I'd like to programmatically turn off the gradle build message 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'.  Is that possible?

I have seen: [How do I turn off in console gradle build message like 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527325/how-do-i-turn-off-in-console-gradle-build-message-like-build-successful) however, that appears to be more about printing the version.

---

**Update:**

- `gradle -q` isn't an option in this case
- by programmatically, I was wondering if there was an API call I could make from my build.gradle

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "programmatically". Is `gradle -q` a solution to your problem?

Comment: besides using `-q` there is no api to remove this message from a gradle build run

Comment: @ReneGroeschke anyway to enable `-q` from build.gradle?

Comment: @Rage, I'm not sure whether it can be set via `StartParameter`.

Comment: @Opal I wasn't able to figure out how to use `LogLevel.QUIET` or just `--quiet' with `StartParameter` Let me know if you find something.

Comment: Filter with `grep -v`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to take on the entire burden of handling log messages yourself, you could override the default logger via the `Gradle.useLogger()` method.

```
gradle.useLogger(new CustomEventLogger())

class CustomEventLogger extends BuildAdapter implements TaskExecutionListener {

    public void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        println "[$task.name]"
    }

    public void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {
        println()
    }

}


task foo() << {
    println 'bar'
}
```

Which results in the output:

```
> gradle foo
[foo]
bar
```

**Note**: Please be aware that if all proper interfaces are not implemented, this approach can suppress errors, making debugging tricky. For instance, there is no task `bar`, running `gradle bar` returns absolutely no output with the implementation above.

```
> gradle bar
>
```